# How to check if the first column of a matrix contains a value from a vector

Tags: r, function

```
fn <- function(D, e) {
  for(i in 1:nrow(D)) {
    if(D[i,1] == e) {
      print("y")
    }
  }
}

fn(events, "a")
```

Problem: `events` is a 2-by-n matrix. If instead of `"a"`, I want to pass `c("a","b","c")` in `e`, then how to check `if(D[i,1]==e)` condition?

Comment: Welcome to SO. A few spaces and some indentation go a long way in terms of readability.

Comment: will keep in mind..thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simple:

```
if any((D[i, 1] %in% e))
```

Comment: What is the difference in if any((D[i, 1] %in% e)) and if (D[i, 1] %in% e)? Former one is not working for me while later one is.

Comment: Please try `?any` and `?all` on your R interpreter. `any` collapses a vector of boolean values into one if any of the values are TRUE.

Answer (score 2):

I would approach it like this:

```
x <- matrix(sample(letters, 25), ncol = 5)

> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] "k"  "v"  "n"  "l"  "f" 
[2,] "w"  "c"  "y"  "r"  "i" 
[3,] "u"  "p"  "o"  "q"  "j" 
[4,] "g"  "s"  "d"  "t"  "x" 
[5,] "a"  "z"  "b"  "h"  "m" 

e <- c("r", "e", "d")
apply(x, 1, function(x, e) any(x %in% e), e = e)

[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```